# Assigning different values to a name in HTML checkbox input based on check status

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input tag as follows as part of a form submission.

```
<input type=“checkbox” id=“allowcheatmode” name=allowCheatMode value=“NO” onchange=“allowCheatModes()”>
```

And allowCheatModes in a JS function

```
function allowCheatModes(){
   var x = document.getElementById(“allowcheatmode”).checked
   if (x) {
      document.getElementById(“allowcheatmode”).value = “YES”
   } else {
      document.getElementById(“allowcheatmode”).value = “NO”
   }
```

But this is not working when I am trying to print the `allowcheatmode` variable after form submission. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Quick guess: Don't you need to put your `if` `else` clause into the `function allowCheatModes()`? Otherwise: What would trigger your clause to be executed after a change?

Comment: The `if ... else ...` should be _in_ `allowCheatModes()`. And changing the `.value` property of a checkbox doesn't "print" anything.

Comment: There should be an error in the console (and there will be more after fixing the the first) -> [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You have included an invalid character `“` and `”`. You should use `"` in both HTML and JS.

```
var x = document.getElementById(“allowcheatmode”).checked
```

**2)** There is no function named `getElemenetById`, instead use `getElementById`.

**3)** Add `if-else` code in the `onChange` function itself. So that it can trigger when checkbox value changes

**NOTE** I've added an extra label to just show the current state of the checkbox. You can skip that part.

```js
function allowCheatModes() {
  var x = document.getElementById("allowcheatmode").checked
  if (x) {
    document.querySelector("label").textContent = "YES"
    document.getElementById("allowcheatmode").value = "YES"
  } else {
    document.querySelector("label").textContent = "NO"
    document.getElementById("allowcheatmode").value = "NO"
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="allowcheatmode" name="allowCheatMode" value="NO" onchange="allowCheatModes()">
<label for="allowcheatmode">NO</label>
```

Comment: This works only when checkbox is checked. It is not working when it not checked

Comment: Sorry to say this. But it does not. When I submit the form in checked stage, It works fine and I am able to print the variable allowCheatMode at other places. But when it is not checked, the form submission itself does not complete.

Comment: Then you might need to add full code. This might help

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Issue was at some other part of the code

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be this:

```
function allowCheatModes(){
    var x = document.getElementById(“allowcheatmode”).checked
    if (x) {
        document.getElemenetById(“allowcheatmode”).value = “YES”
    } else {
         document.getElemenetById(“allowcheatmode”).value = “NO”
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function allowCheatModes(){
    var isChecked = document.getElementById("allowcheatmode").checked;

    if (isChecked) {
      document.getElementById("allowcheatmode").value = "YES";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("allowcheatmode").value = "NO";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="allowcheatmode" name="allowCheatMode" value="NO" onchange="allowCheatModes()">
```

The code above will be valid, because you had typo in getElemenetById (should be getElementById, not getElemeNETById). Anyway, you will see nothing in this case, because input with type="checkbox" have no view. You can improve your code adding some div element:

```js
function allowCheatModes(){
    var isChecked = document.getElementById("allowcheatmode").checked;
    
    document.getElementById("allowcheatmode-view").innerHTML = isChecked ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="allowcheatmode" name="allowCheatMode" onchange="allowCheatModes()">

<div id="allowcheatmode-view">NO</div>
```

P.S.: "condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse" is ternary operator, the short form of "if"

Answer (score 0):

You did two things wrong

---

First thing

You put if outside the function, please put if inside the function

```
function allowCheatModes() {
...
}
```

Replace with

```
function allowCheatModes() {
...
  if(x){
    ...
  }
}
```

---

Second thing

The function name you are using is wrong, you should use getElementById, not getElemenetById

```
document.getElemenetById
```

Replace with

```
document.getElementById
```

---

Below is my adjusted snippet, you can refer to it.

Have a good day :)

```js
function allowCheatModes(){
  var x = document.getElementById("allowcheatmode").checked;
  if (x) {
     document.getElementById("allowcheatmode").value = "YES"
  } else {
     document.getElementById("allowcheatmode").value = "NO"
  }
  console.log(document.getElementById("allowcheatmode").value);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="allowcheatmode" name="allowCheatMode" value="NO" onchange="allowCheatModes()">
```